# how to not lose tables values in asp.net when the function page_load Avoke

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqlcommand

I created a dynamic table in VB.NET on asp.net page and its shows right .
But when I try to read the table on a click even I wrote: `tablename.rows.count` it shows `0` , in me page i see the table and the rows .

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Are you sure Rachel is C#? I can see VB.NET in the code I edited your question.

Comment: is this row in created using JS?

Answer (score 0):

How do you persist the table between pages?  You state that you created a "dynamic" table which suggest that it isn't stored on disk or in a database somewhere. The quick way to deal with this is to store it in the `Session` object like so:

```
Session("MyDataTable") = MyDataTable
```

In the click event you retreive the datatable like so:

```
MyDataTable = Session("MyDataTable")
```

using the basic session object requires that the client have session cookies turned on, there are other ways to deal with session (and persisting data), but this is the quick and dirty way.